# How can I change the default color of usecases in Tikz-UML?

Tags: color, tikz-uml

I am using tikz-uml and I want to make all the use cases filled with white instead of the default one. Do you know how can I set all the usecases with white as color?

I know that I can write "fill = white" in the options of each usecase but I want to avoid that and set white as default.

Currently this is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tikzumlset{}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every edge} = [link]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\umlusecase[x=0, y=0, name=Checkout, fill = white]{Checkout}
\umlusecase[right = 2cm of Checkout]{Customer Authentication}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key that you are looking for is:

```
\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white}
```

If you want to define a custom variation which occurs often but not always (which may include more than just `fill` - remember these usecases are still tikz nodes, so anything you are used to for nodes can be changed here as well),  you can do this via:

```
\tikzset{myumlcase/.style={fill=red,font=\huge}}
```

This will overwrite the general `fill` setting (here white) when you specify `myumlcase` in the options of the `\umlusecase[myumlcase]{foo}`.

Here is your edited (and working) MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tikzumlset{}

\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white} % This is the general color switch

\tikzset{myumlcase/.style={fill=red,font=\huge}} % Defines special umlcase with the name myumlcase

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every edge} = [link]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlusecase[x=0, y=0, name=Checkout, fill = white,myumlcase]{Checkout}
\umlusecase[right = 2cm of Checkout]{Customer Authentication}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To find further keys you may want to change in the future you can look into the tikz-uml.sty, the [TikZ-UML manual](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf) (section 2.6) and of course the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).